# Which Enid Blyton Faraway Tree book has a boy being given pilchard ice cream

Tags: story-identification, novel, food

I read this in about 1976. One of the lands that stopped at the top of the Faraway Tree had a man giving away free ice-creams. He tells the  children he has every flavour so they can ask for whatever kind they like.

One boy does not believe the generous man has every flavour. He tries to embarrass the man by asking for pilchard ice cream. He is sure the man will not have this weird food he just made up.

The man does indeed give him pilchard ice cream. The other children ask for more palatable flavours.

The pilchard ice cream tastes absolutely foul and he cannot bring himself to eat it.

The boy asks if he can have a  different flavour. The ice cream man tells him he cannot have another until he has eaten up his first.

I have tried Google and Goodreads but maybe I am not searching skillfully enough.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It was the third book of the series, *[The Folk of the Faraway Tree](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/473623)* as per [this review](https://worldofblyton.com/2014/10/01/the-folk-of-the-faraway-tree-review-by-laura/):

> There’s another serious adventure close to the end of the book – the Faraway Tree appears to be withering up and dying – and a visit to one of the more pleasant lands at the end as a reward. The Land of Treats was always one of my favourites – I loved the idea of an ice-cream man who could produce any flavour you ask for. Connie is still a bit sceptical, even after everything she’s been through, and asks for sardine ice cream. Naturally she gets it and has to give it to a cat, as she certainly can’t eat it herself.

It looks like it's actually an order for "fish ice-cream"

> So when her turn came she said solemnly, ‘I want a fish ice-cream please.’
>
> And hey presto! The ice cream man just as solemnly handed her out a large ice-cream which was quite obviously made of fish because the others could see a few fish bones sticking out of it!
>
> ‘Ha, ha, Connie! Serves you right!’ said Joe.
>
> Connie looked at the ice-cream and wrinkled up her nose. She handed it to the ice-cream man, and said ‘I won’t have this. I’ll have a strawberry one, please.’

Found with a search for `"faraway tree" "ice cream"`

Comment: Yes, this is it  thank you. I am out of votes but will of course give you a +1 after midnight.

Comment: Which is why my searches including pilchard didn't work 

Comment: The quote you posted says this fish is sardine. My six year old self obviously misremembered which strongly flavoured fish the ice cream was made from.

Comment: Indeed, the review calls out sardines, but the book copy I found just said fish.

Comment: The later editions of the books have had a few words changed. Maybe they decided too few modern children were familar with sardines?